# Часть речи слова «всë»

Tags: морфология, части-речи

***Врешь ты всë!***

Какова часть речи слова ***всë*** в этом предложении?

Это существительное-дополнение при глаголе врать (сравните: ты врëшь *про всë / обо всëм*)?

Или же *всë* — это наречие со значением "всегда, постоянно", короче, с каким-то обстоятельственным значением?

Сравните: *он *всë* спит*; *его всë нет;* и даже *он всë врëт и врëт*. Во всех этих примерах *всë* в общем значении указывает на некое постоянство действия, то есть является признаком действия, а стало быть, и наречием.

Comment: Вечер добрый, Хай Дзяо! Я бы ещё шапку изменила: *Часть речи слова «всë»*.

Comment: Хай Дзяо, скажите, пожалуйста, а почему Вы не голосуете, то есть не отмечаете полезность вопросов-ответов? Разве нет достойных, интересных? У Вас ведь всего один голос за все время. Интересно...

Comment: Врёшь ты всё - местоимение, - врёшь что? - всё, врёшь ты это вот.  он всë спит - наречие, сокращение от оборота всё ещё,з заменимо на  "по-прежнему". Чтобы в фразе со "врёт" было наречие, нужно говорить "он всяко врёт". Ну и: врёшь ты всё! - что я вру-то? - да всё! Вопрос обстоятельный не задашь с ответом "всё" не задашь: врёшь ты всё! - когда я вру? - всегда!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К слову сказать, вот статья из БАС 1951 года. Переходность фиксируется в одном из значений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути, *врать* (с управлением винительным падежом) в указанном значении близок к *перевирать ***что-то****, *искажать **что-то**  враньём*, выдумывать какую-то неправду.

Comment: По-моему,  **болтать** и **пустословить** из приведённого Вами словаря — это  совсем не «выдумывать какую-то неправду».

Comment: Вы не забывайте, что любое словарное толкование, любая дефиниция — это личное мнение лексикографа. Врать всякий вздор - это, как по мне, именно генерировать, выдумывать какую-то чушь.

Comment: врать всякий вздор - выдумывать что-то волнующее, провокационное, резонансное. генерировать - рождать. У Пушкина ври - говорить, не следя речью, за выражениями, за тем, кому ты это говоришь, с какой целью, по-простому Пушкин сказал: фильтруй базар, дядя, следи за выражениями.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Теория по теме**

В словаре **[Ефремовой](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/149424)** указано:

**I всё, мест.** 1. Употребляется при указании на нераздельное, цельное, взятое в полном объёме. **II всё, нареч. обстоят. времени** разг. 1. Беспрерывно, постоянно (о чём-либо повторяющемся).

Также есть информация о возможности **перехода** местоимения в **существительное,** например: Все (***все*** пассажиры) отошли от края платформы. Также: ***Всё*** (все сказанное тобой) неправда.

2. **Решение задачи**

***Врешь ты все.***

В принципе здесь возможны **оба** значения, выбор **по контексту.** Но я  думаю, что вариант зависит и  от **порядка** слов.

(1) ***Врешь ты всё.  Всё ты врешь.*** Это существительное в значении дополнения.

Например: *Врешь ты **всё**, ничего этого не было.*

(2) ***Ты всё врешь.*** Эта позиция более **свободная,** здесь возможны оба значения:

*Ты **всё** врешь, ничего этого не было.* Существительное в значении **дополнения.**

*Ты **всё** врешь, я смотрю. Что на этот раз рассказываешь?* Это **наречие** со значением "постоянно" в роли **обстоятельства**.

Comment: Но вопрос-то вы задаёте к местоимению: что на этот раз.../ а не когда на этот раз?

Comment: @Буратино Здесь не про то, вы меня не поняли :( Человек постоянно врет или сочиняет. В прошлый раз рассказывал одну сомнительную историю, а теперь опять что-то рассказывает. Интересно, что на этот раз? Вот в чем смысл вопроса и эпизода.  Можно записать так: Ты все (опять) врешь?  Значение обстоятельства.  Что теперь ты врешь?   Перех. значение у глагола "врать", функция прямого дополнения у местоимения ЧТО.

Comment: Но ведь можно сказать: "опять? ты опять?" Но со "всё" так не скажешь, следовательно "опять" не эквивалентно "всё".

Comment: @Буратино Спасибо, я отвечу вам в поле ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Примерный диалог:

> — *Я видел то-то и то-то.*
>
> — ***Врёшь ты всё!** Ничего ты не видел!*

Думаю, что в подобных контекстах ***всё*** не является членом предложения и близко по значению **к частице**, к которой **никакого** вопроса ни от сказуемого, ни от подлежащего задать не получится.

В параллельном (уже принятом) ответе в этой теме высказано предположение, что ***всё*** в предложении ***Врёшь ты всё!*** — это «существительное в значении дополнения». Получается, что ***всё*** стоит в винительном падеже  и глагол ***врать*** тогда — **переходный?**

Но сможет ли кто-нибудь привести хоть один пример  из русской литературы, в котором глагол ***врать*** сочетался бы с винительным падежом существительного?..

Comment: Частица? Укажите, с каким значением. ВСЁ II. частица (со сл., обозначающим изменяющийся признак). Указывает на нарастание или устойчивость признака. Шум всё сильней. Больной всё слабеет.  Врешь все сильней? Да?   // Или думаете, что не рассматривался вариант с частицей. //  А.С. Пушкин:  Ах ты, мерзкое стекло! Это врешь ты мне назло!   Оценка  сказанного ранее, а не усиление значения. // В значении сущ. (подлежащее) Эх, ребята, всё не так! Всё не так, ребята!

Comment: Врать. То значение, которое имеет этот глагол сегодня, появилось лишь в недавнее время. Еще при Пушкине можно было услышать: «Полно врать пустяки». Почти как в выражении «говорить глупости». Первоначальное значение глагола врать — «говорить» указывает на его родство, скажем, с немецким Wort — «слово» и с латинским verbum — «глагол».

Comment: https://gramota.ru/poisk?mode=slovari&query=врать&simple=0  врать
ГрамматикаСемантика
Глагол, несовершенный вид, переходный
совершенный вид
что. Говорить неправду; сочинять небылицы; лгать, обманывать.

Comment: @Sharon, по-моему, вы путаете глагол «врать» со значением «говорить» (как это было во времена Пушкина) с современным глаголом «врать» со значением «лгать». Но если Вы настаиваете на возможности сочетания современного глагола «врать» с винительным падежом существительного — переубеждать Вас не буду. 

Comment: Да уж, вряд ли получится.  Ваш пример как раз по теме.  Сообщение: Я видел то-то и то-то. Реакция;  Врешь (= сочиняешь) ты все (прямое дополнение). В смысле: врешь (=сочиняешь) все, что сказал.  Надо только увидеть здесь значение прямого дополнения.

Comment: Врать - это вообще сниженная лексика.  У Даля: говорить вздор, небылицу, пустяки. Не так уж много времени прошло с тех пор, чтобы переходное значение совсем забылось.  Здесь можно вспомнить об ИДИОМАТИЧЕСКИХ выражениях, где используется  прежняя грамматика.  А вот значение ЧАСТИЦЫ я не вижу ни в одном словаре.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ на комментарий  @Буратино**  (с учетом всего сказанного по теме, а также с примером из русской литературы)

```
 Получается, что всё стоит в винительном падеже и глагол 
 врать тогда — переходный? Но сможет ли кто-нибудь привести 
 хоть один пример из русской литературы, в котором глагол 
 врать сочетался бы с винительным падежом 
 существительного?..

 По-моему, вы путаете глагол «врать» со значением 
 «говорить» (как это было во времена Пушкина) с современным 
 глаголом «врать» со значением «лгать». Но если Вы 
 настаиваете на возможности сочетания современного глагола 
 «врать» с винительным падежом существительного — 
 переубеждать Вас не буду.
```

Так как там говорили, **во времена Пушкина?**

```
 «А смею спросить, — продолжал он, — зачем изволили вы 
 перейти из гвардии в гарнизон?» Я отвечал, что такова была 
 воля начальства. «Чаятельно, за неприличные гвардии офицеру 
 поступки», — продолжал неутомимый вопрошатель. «ПОЛНО ВРАТЬ  
 ПУСТЯКИ, — сказала ему капитанша, — ты видишь, молодой 
 человек с дороги устал; ему не до тебя..." 
 Капитанская дочка.
```

1. Давайте будем отличать **семантику от грамматики.**

**Семантика:** если что-то делается опять и снова, то это делается постоянно, ***ВСЕгда.*** Вот и появляется слово «всё».  У него основное значение — **обобщение**.  А  функция в данном случае — **обстоятельство.**

А вот другая грамматика: ***всё — вранье,  врешь ты всё.***  Здесь предметное значение, функция **дополнения и подлежащего**.  Но семантика та же: **обобщение**.

Так что в моем ответе не так?  Укажите точно.

2. И **контрольный  вопрос** по теме: может ли глагол «врать"  в настоящее время иметь значение **переходности**, как во времена Пушкина?  Или мы однажды забыли про всё, проснувшись поутру?

Не так уж много времени прошло с тех пор, чтобы переходное значение совсем забылось. Здесь можно вспомнить также об **идиоматических** (устойчивых) выражениях, где используется **прежняя грамматика**.

**ИЗ СЛОВАРЕЙ** (семантика)

**ВЕСЬ**, всего; м.; ВСЯ, всей; ж.; ВСЁ, всего; ср.; ВСЕ, всех, вин. неодуш.: все; вин. одуш.: всех. мн.; местоим. прил. 1. Такой, который рассматривается **в полном объёме; целый, полный**.

**ВСЁ,** I местоим. 1. Употребляется при указании на **нераздельное, цельное,** взятое в полном объёме. 2. Употребляется как **обобщающее** слово при перечислении.